# Left join in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two records in table 1 and 0 records in table 2. I have this query.

```
br_id project_id detail price
 1    1239      abc     50
 2    1239      xyz    100
```

table 2 this empty at the moment

```
id break_id project_id complete breakamount




SELECT t1.*,sum(t2.complete) as brcompletedwork, 
       sum(t2.breakamount) as breakpaidamount 
FROM tbl_projectbreakdown t1 
LEFT JOIN tbl_breakdownpayment t2 ON 
    t2.break_id=t1.br_id 
WHERE t1.project_id=1239 
ORDER BY t2.break_id
```

This show only one record. What seems to be problem?

If I get t2.* then show all records but I am getting sum from second table against break_id

Comment: `aggregate` function without `group by` shows only one row, you need to do a `group by` perhaps `group by t1.project_id`

Comment: Also move your WHERE condition to `LEFT JOIN ON blah AND someotherblah`

Comment: be very cautious of MySQL's very peculiar "extension" to `GROUP BY`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html . If you want accurate results do not use t1.* in select clause with only group by t1.project_id. Match the group by clause with the non-aggregating columns of the select clause and you will avoid this MySQL trap.

Comment: you really need to provide sample data and expected result, we are left guessing as to what your data looks like and what the objective really is.

Comment: No better answers possible without a dump of your table. Is there a small sample dataset available which can be used to properly reproduce your problem? We're working blind here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the benefit of data and expected result, proposed answers are based on some guesswork. {some data now available, change to join as result}

Your existing query needs a `GROUP BY` clause. Be very cautious of MySQL's very peculiar "extension" to `GROUP BY`. See [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) . If you want accurate results do not use t1.* in the select clause with only group by of a small numbers of fields. Match the group by clause with the non-aggregating columns of the select clause and you will avoid this MySQL trap.

At this point I see no inherent problem with your existing where clause as it references T1 and not the outer joined T2.

```
SELECT
      t1.project_id
    , t1.br_id
    , SUM( t2.complete ) AS brcompletedwork
    , SUM( t2.breakamount ) AS breakpaidamount
FROM tbl_projectbreakdown t1
      LEFT JOIN tbl_breakdownpayment t2 ON t1.br_id = t2.break_id
                                       AND t1.project_id = t2.project_id
WHERE t1.project_id = 1239
GROUP BY
      t1.project_id
    , t1.br_id
ORDER BY t1.br_id
;
```

However as you are joining tables there is a potential for rows to be multiplied and this can be a problem when summing. Often it is necessary to sum **before** joining so the results remain accurate.

```
SELECT
      t1.project_id
    , t1.br_id
    , t2.brcompletedwork
    , t2.breakpaidamount
FROM tbl_projectbreakdown t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT project_id
                , break_id
                , SUM( complete ) AS brcompletedwork
                , SUM( breakamount ) AS breakpaidamount
            FROM tbl_breakdownpayment
            GROUP BY project_id, break_id) t2 ON t1.br_id = t2.break_id
                                             AND t1.project_id = t2.project_id
WHERE t1.project_id = 1239
GROUP BY
      t1.project_id
    , t1.br_id
ORDER BY t1.br_id
;
```

I suggest using `t1.br_id` instead of `t2.break_id` in the select and group by clauses because with that outer join `t2.break_id` can be NULL but `t1.br_id` present.

Comment: This work only at that time when table 2 having data. if table 2 empty then only display one records.

Comment: incorrect. the left join does NOT prohibit rows from T1 to display

Comment: Then "tick" the answer that worked for you please, this indicates you have your solution.

Comment: thank you, accepting an answer is appreciated and helps future readers also.

Answer (score 0):

You have WHERE statement in your query. Remove it to get all results:

```
select t1.*,sum(t2.complete) as brcompletedwork,sum(t2.breakamount) as breakpaidamount 
from tbl_projectbreakdown t1 
LEFT JOIN tbl_breakdownpayment t2 ON t2.break_id=t1.br_id
order by t2.break_id
```

Comment: Getting same result only one row. Actually me need all records against project_id

Comment: If I get t2.* then show all records but I am getting sum from second table against break_id

Answer (score 0):

You have used aggregate function sum which will sum all the rows. So remove where statement and add group by. Now it will group on break_id and give you sum per break_id.

```
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.break_id,
       sum(t2.complete) AS brcompletedwork,
       sum(t2.breakamount) AS breakpaidamount
  FROM tbl_projectbreakdown t1
       LEFT JOIN tbl_breakdownpayment t2 ON t2.break_id = t1.br_id
WHERE t1.project_id=1239 
GROUP BY t2.break_id
ORDER BY t2.break_id
```

Comment: Getting same result only one row. Actually me need all records against project_id

Comment: I need sum against break_id not against project_id

Comment: Try now. I have added the where statement and now grouping is done on breakid but to do that this column must be added in select statement.

Comment: Are there multiple break_id against this project_id?

Comment: Yes there will be multiple break_id against project_id

Comment: this is working at that time when table 2 having data. but if table 2 empty then show only one record

Comment: That because group by is done on table 2 column. In case there is no data that column will have null value. As all column has null values so group by on null will merge them into 1 row. If you run the query with no data in table 2, t2.break_id would have (null) am i right?